# android -How to update application inside application

Tags: android

I've seen this in some application , the application size is about 6 mb but it download a file about 100kb and update the application .

it's very interesting , I've searched alot but I couldn't find any way to do it .

How can I do so ?

thanks

Comment: what make you interesting, Just create a simple app with structure and publish it, when it open for first time download all the data from your server, simple

Comment: That's called "incremental update".

Answer (score 0):

I do it using the below class, but it does require downloading the new APK, so it may not be exactly what you need. It is done this way because we do not use the play store.
If there is an update available, start the Runnable class.
It starts the download, and when the download is completed it asks if you want to update, then starts the update.
All you need to do is figure out how to host the APK file. I use a windows server and IIS7, with a mime setup so it is recognized by android as an installable APK.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetUpdate implements Runnable{
    Context cxt;
    String line;
    String filepath = "";
    int continueornot=0;
    ProgressBar progBar;
    Button buttOk;
    DownloadManager mgr=null; 
    long lastDownload=-1L; 


    public GetUpdate(Context contextIn, String lineIn, ProgressBar progressBar,Button okButtIn){
        cxt = contextIn;
        line = lineIn;
        this.progBar = progressBar;
        this.buttOk = okButtIn;


    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        filepath = cxt.getExternalFilesDir("/MyFileStorage/").getAbsolutePath();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(cxt);

        alert.setTitle("Update Availible");
        alert.setMessage("Start the download?");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        //final EditText serverURL = new EditText(cxt);
        //alert.setView(serverURL);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //String tempFilepath = cxt.getExternalFilesDir("/MyFileStorage/").getAbsolutePath();
                File myExternalFile = new File(filepath);

                File[] sdDirList = myExternalFile.listFiles(); 
                if(sdDirList != null){
                    for(int x=0;x<sdDirList.length;x++){
                        String fileNameString = sdDirList[x].toString();
                        System.out.println("File: " + sdDirList[x].toString());

                        if(fileNameString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("podcodes.txt")
                                ||fileNameString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("vehiclesTrailers.txt")                                
                                ||fileNameString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("checks.txt")
                                ||sdDirList[x].toString().endsWith(".apk")){

                            sdDirList[x].delete();
                        }
                    }
                }

                BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() { 
                    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) { 

                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(cxt);

                        alert.setTitle("Update Availible");
                        alert.setMessage("Start the update?");

                        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                Toast.makeText(cxt.getApplicationContext(), "Updating!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                                String lastDownloaded = mgr.getUriForDownloadedFile(lastDownload).toString();
                                //String lastDownloadFileName = lastDownloaded.substring(lastDownloaded.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(lastDownloaded), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                cxt.startActivity(intent);
                                Globals.setExit(true);
                            }
                        });

                        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttOk.setText("OK");
                                buttOk.setEnabled(true);
                                buttOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        });

                        alert.show();
                    } 
                }; 

                mgr=(DownloadManager)cxt.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 
                cxt.registerReceiver(onComplete, 
                        new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)); 

                BroadcastReceiver onNotificationClick=new BroadcastReceiver() { 
                    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) { 
                        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Downloading InCab Update!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } 
                }; 
                cxt.registerReceiver(onNotificationClick, 
                        new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED)); 


                Uri uri=Uri.parse(Globals.getServerURL()+"/LatestAndroid/"+line.trim()); 
                //Environment 
                //  .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("MyFileStorage/"+line.trim()) 
                //  .mkdirs(); 

                lastDownload= 
                        mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri) 
                        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | 
                                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true) 
                                .setTitle(line.trim()) 
                                .setDescription("Incab Update.")
                                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(cxt,"MyFileStorage", line.trim()));




                Toast.makeText(cxt.getApplicationContext(), "Downloading!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                continueornot=1;
                progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
                buttOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttOk.setText("Downloading..");
                buttOk.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                continueornot=2;                
                progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttOk.setText("OK");
                buttOk.setEnabled(true);
                buttOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //cancel(true);
            }
        });

        alert.show();   

        progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttOk.setText("OK");
        buttOk.setEnabled(true);
        buttOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } 


}
```